# Finitely general abelian groups, isomorphisms, integers mod n, question.

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook claims $\mathbb{Z}_2$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_4$ $\ncong$ $\mathbb{Z}_8$ but that $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$.
Can someone help me understand why this is?

Comment: Is it because in the first case gcd(2,4) $\neq$ 1 while in the second case gcd(2,4,9) = 1? If so why would this make all the difference? I think we would just consider pairwise relatively prime cases?

Comment: This is not true. There is no element of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ (every element has order dividing $\text{lcm}(2,4,9) = 36$), but there is one in $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ (e.g. $(1,0)$)

Comment: @user115654: I believe your comment should be made into an answer.

Comment: @rghthndsd: Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

This is not true. There is no element of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ (every element has order dividing $\text{lcm}(2,4,9) = 36$), but there is one in $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ (e.g. $(1,0)$).

Comment: Oh you're right, I misread what my textbook was saying, *sigh*. Yeah it makes sense.
You can only break it down to powers of prime numbers.

Comment: Good that it's cleared up now!

Answer (score 0):

There's a theorem that states if one isomorphism exist between two modular classes, then there exists an isomorphism between modular classes being represented by the previous primes.

In the first case you provided, the theorem doesn't hold because the modular class 4 is not isomorphic to the modular class 8. Sorry if this us hard to follow. I'm in my tablet right now :/

If there are anymore questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Adam, I believe that you are correct when you say that it is because 2 and 8 are not coprime! The explanation I can give off the top of my head follows from how we prove that the map $\phi:a+\mathbb{Z/nmZ} \rightarrow (a+\mathbb{Z/nZ},a+\mathbb{Z/mZ})$ is an isomorphism for coprime m and n.

First, we note that an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism, so we need to show (1) that $\phi$ is a homomorphism and (2) that $\phi$ is bijective.

(1) $\phi$ is trivially a homomorphism because $\mathbb{Z/nZ} \times \mathbb{Z/mZ}$ is a group, and $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b) \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z/mnZ}$

(2) a. $\phi$ is injective because $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$ if and only if a=b. An ordered pair is only equal if their components are equal.

b. $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $\forall a+\mathbb{Z/n},b+\mathbb{Z/mZ}$, $\exists c$ such that $\phi(c+\mathbb{Z/nmZ})=(a+\mathbb{Z/nZ},b+\mathbb{Z/mZ}).$ Note that this statement is equivalent to:
$$c \equiv a \pmod{n}$$
$$c \equiv b \pmod{m}$$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, this system has a unique solution c if m and n are coprime.

So the point is, if they are not coprime, then the map is not necessarily surjective and the groups may not be isomorphic! This is illustrated in your example: $\mathbb{Z/8Z}\times\mathbb{Z/9Z}\ncong \mathbb{Z/2Z} \times \mathbb{Z/4Z}\times \mathbb{Z/9Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z/8Z}\ncong \mathbb{Z/2Z} \times \mathbb{Z/4Z}$, since 1 has order 8 in $\mathbb{Z/8Z}$, while there is no element of order 8 in $\mathbb{Z/2Z} \times \mathbb{Z/4Z}$.

I hope this helped!